# Allowing pop-up's and downloads with flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I'm building an flex app that is basically a wrapper for a few websites. One of them is a google docs website, and I'm trying to get flex to allow downloads or popups or something that will allow me to do it. I've tried a whole bunch of solutions online and none of them have worked out. Here's the code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       width="100%" height="100%"
                        creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">

    <s:layout>
        <s:HorizontalLayout/>
    </s:layout>
    <fx:Style source="style.css"/>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            include "CustomHTMLLoader.as";

            private function onCreationComplete():void
            {
                // ... other stuff ...
                var custom:object;
                custom.htmlHost = new MyHTMLHost();
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%" backgroundColor="#87BED0" styleName="container">
        <s:Panel x="188" y="17" width="826" height="112" borderAlpha="0.15" chromeColor="#0C5A74"
                 color="#FFFFFF" cornerRadius="20" dropShadowVisible="false" enabled="true"
                 title="Customer Service Control Panel">
            <s:controlBarContent/>

            <s:Button id="home" x="13" y="10" height="44" label="Phones"
                      click="myViewStack.selectedChild=Home;" enabled="true"
                      icon="@Embed('assets/iconmonstr-mobile-phone-6-icon-32.png')"/>
            <s:Button id="liveagent" x="131" y="10" height="44" label="Live Agent"
                      click="myViewStack.selectedChild=live_agent;"
                      icon="@Embed('assets/iconmonstr-speech-bubble-11-icon-32.png')"/>
            <s:Button id="bigcommerce" x="260" y="10" width="158" height="44" label="Big Commerce"
                      click="myViewStack.selectedChild=bigcommerce_home;"
                      icon="@Embed('assets/iconmonstr-coin-6-icon-48.png')"/>
            <s:Button id="faq" x="436" y="10" width="88" height="44" label="FAQ"
                      click="myViewStack.selectedChild=freqaskquestions;" fontFamily="Arial"
                      icon="@Embed('assets/iconmonstr-help-4-icon-32.png')"/>
            <s:Button id="call" x="540" y="10" width="131" height="44" label="Google Docs"
                      click="myViewStack.selectedChild=call_notes;"
                      icon="@Embed('assets/iconmonstr-text-file-4-icon-32.png')"/>
            <s:Button id="hoot" x="684" y="10" width="122" height="44" label="HootSuite"
                      click="myViewStack.selectedChild=hoot_suite;"
                      icon="@Embed('assets/iconmonstr-facebook-icon-32.png')"/>
        </s:Panel>
        <mx:ViewStack id="myViewStack" x="0" y="140" width="100%" height="100%" borderStyle="solid">
            <s:NavigatorContent id="Home">
                <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                    <mx:HTML x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false"
                             horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                             location="http://mbvphone.mtbakervapor.org/vbx/messages/inbox"
                             />
                </s:BorderContainer>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="bigcommerce_home">
                <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:HTML  x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false"
                         horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                         location="http://www.mtbakervapor.com/admin"
                         />
                </s:BorderContainer>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="live_agent">
                <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                    <mx:HTML x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false"
                             horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                             location="http://mbvphone.mtbakervapor.org/liveagent/agent/#login"
                             />
                </s:BorderContainer>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="freqaskquestions">
                <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                    <mx:HTML x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false"
                             horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                             location="http://mbvphone.mtbakervapor.org/liveagent/"
                             />
                </s:BorderContainer>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="call_notes">
                <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                    <mx:HTML id="html" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false"
                             horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                             location="https://drive.google.com/a/mtbakervapor.com/"
                             htmlHost="{new CustomHost()}"
                             />
                </s:BorderContainer>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
            <s:NavigatorContent id="hoot_suite">
                <s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="100%">
                    <mx:HTML x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" borderVisible="false"
                             horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
                             location="https://hootsuite.com/login"
                             />
                </s:BorderContainer>
            </s:NavigatorContent>
        </mx:ViewStack>
        <s:Image x="0" y="0" width="180" height="140" scaleMode="letterbox" smooth="false"
                 source="assets/mbvlogo_black.png"/>
    </s:BorderContainer>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

and the custom class code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.html.HTMLHost;
    import flash.html.HTMLWindowCreateOptions;
    import flash.html.HTMLLoader;

    public class MyHTMLHost extends HTMLHost
    {
        public function MyHTMLHost(defaultBehaviors:Boolean=true)
        {
            super(defaultBehaviors);
        }

        override public function createWindow(windowCreateOptions:HTMLWindowCreateOptions):HTMLLoader
        {
            // all JS calls and HREFs to open a new window should use the existing window
            return HTMLLoader.createRootWindow();
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Downloads or popups for what purpose?  You mean downloads/popups from the Flex application?  Or from the HTML application?  Or something different?  Can you please be more specific about what you're trying to do and what the error you're receiving is.  From my perception you've included a lot of code; but I do not know what I would be looking for.

Comment: From within the application yes, for example say I wanted to download an file from my google drive. Right now clicking the download button does nothing.

Comment: Then show your code for your download button so we can get a feel for what you are doing?  Or is this a Google Docs download button in the remote HTML page you are loading?

Comment: @Reboog711 Yeah it's just a button link in the remote HTML of the site.